# Implement custom theme in react using reactdatagrid

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

When trying to follow https://reactdatagrid.io/docs/api-reference#props-theme it loads the table with no styling/themes

I have done this in my theme file

```
$DATAGRID_THEME_NAME: 'data-table-red';
$INOVUA_DATAGRID_ACCENT_COLOR: rgb(230, 0, 0);

@import '@inovua/reactdatagrid-community/style/base.scss';
@import '@inovua/reactdatagrid-community/style/theme/default-light/index.scss';
// @import '~@inovua/reactdatagrid-community/style/index.scss'

$DATAGRID_THEME_NAME: 'data-table-red';
$INOVUA_DATAGRID_ACCENT_COLOR: rgb(230, 0, 0);
```

file is called data-table-red.scss

"@inovua/reactdatagrid-community": "^5.10.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",